# Power BI Report Server :: Could not load folder contents

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

I want to migrate a few .rdl files from SSRS to Power BI. In order to do so I'm following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58rLq8MF2mc).

I installed Power BI Report Server which really looks like SSRS and I setup everything correctly.

When I try to login into http://mylaptop/Reports/browse I receive this error:

> Could not load folder contents
>
> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions.

[image]

I read some guide and they say to:

1. Going into Management and create a user. But I cannot because I don't see the Management button
2. Run IE as Administrator. But I cannot because IE has been retired
3. Run another browser as Administrator. I tried but the problem persists.

Where is this folder and how can I change permissions?